# Synthax error in js / missing ) after argument list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

Hi i'm working in node with passport and mongodb for login local session , and i got a synthax error but i can't figure out why? 
[image]

it's kind of weird cause i think i got every thing in order

here here it's my code ...

```js
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../app/models/users');

module.exports = function(passport){
    //Serializing user
    passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
      done(null, user.id);
    });


    passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
      User.findById(id, fuction(err,user){ //here it's the error D:
        done(err,user);
      });
    });

    passport.use('local-signup', new localStrategy({
      usernameField: 'username',
      passField:'pass'
      passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req,username, pass, done){
      process.nextTick(function(){
          User.findOne({'local.emial':email,},function(err,user){
            if(err){
              return done(err);
            }
            if(user){
              retrun done(null,false,req.flash('signupMessage','Thath email its already taken '));
            }else{
              var newUser = new User();
              newUser.local.username = username;
              newUser.local.pass = pass;

              newUser.save(function(err){
                if(err){
                  throw err;
                  return done(null,newUser);
                }
              })
            }
          });
      });
    }


  ));



    // end function
}
```

as always really thanks for your help

Comment: `fuction` => `function` and `retrun` => `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct `fuction` into `function` maybe?

Comment: god bless you :)